# Spring-Retry cannot locate recovery method when implement an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I found a problem when doing spring-retry with spring boot. When a class implements an interface, it cannot enter the @recover method after exceeding the maximum number of retries. But when I inject a normal class, I can enter this method.Your prompt help and kind advices would be much appreciated,thanks!

> When I do this,I can enter the @Recover method

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Retryable(Exception.class)
    public String retry(String c) throws Exception{
        throw new Exception();
    }

    @Recover
    public String recover(Exception e,String c) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("got error");
        return null;
    }
}
```

> But once the class implement another interface, it's not works

```
@Service
public class TestService implements TestServiceI{

    @Override
    @Retryable(Exception.class)
    public String retry(String c) throws Exception{
        throw new Exception();
    }

    @Recover
    public String recover(Exception e,String c) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("got error");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is implemented using proxies and by default interface based proxies are used. Hence you get a class pretending to be a `TestServiceI` but not a `TestService`. Hence when inspecting there is no method annotated with `@Recover` as that is hidden inside the proxy. Configure Spring Retry to use class based proxies.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks,solved the problem ; )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring-Retry uses AOP to implement the `@Retry`. When using AOP the default is to use JDK Dynamic Proxies. JDK Dynamic Proxies are interface based.

This means you get a dynamically created class that pretents to be a `TestServiceI` however it isn't a `TestService`. The proxy doesn't include the `recover` method (as it isn't on the interface) and as such Spring Retry cannot detect it.

To fix you need to enable class based proxies for Spring Retry by setting the `proxyTargetClass` attribute on `@EnableRetry` to `true` (see the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/EnableRetry.html)).

```
@EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

Comment: I have an [open PR to solve this without proxying the class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/pull/124).

Comment: @GaryRussell wouldn't that only work if the `@Recover` annotated method is also on the interface. The OP doesn't have that method in the interface only on the class.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the `@Recover` method would have to be on the interface too for that PR to work.

Answer (score 3):

1. mark proxyTargetClass=true:  @EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass = true)
2. The @Recover method must return the same type as the original method;